# I.E 11 Issue (Data is not showing)

Tags: javascript, database, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, explorer

I am working on the U.I of an existing product where the data is coming on chrome and firefox but on Internet explorer-11 and so on, few of them (in few tabs) it's coming and in few it's not for example if a table data is coming along it's filed name in chrome then same table is showing it's field name but not the the data in Internet Explorer 11.

In console there is no error in I.E-11 but still data is not coming.  I was looking for the solution on stack-overflow then there is recommended that we should use the meta tag like:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"
```

Does it really work? because I was using it on front-end using inspect element on I.E-11 but data was not showing on front end. data is coming on Microsoft Edge as well properly.

Would you people like to recommended any solution for this?

Comment: It's not possible to resolve the problem before the code is coming.

Comment: Hi Teemu, Thank's for replying. The code is confidential so it can't be public. I would like to know about the common solutions which works in such type of cases.

Comment: There are no common cases, every case is individual, especially when you say "_In console there is no error_". And yes, `X-UA-Compatible` works as it's intended to work, but it doesn't convert an IE browser to Edge browser, if you're expecting that to happen.

Comment: @Saurabh, your description about the issue is not enough to find any cause for this issue. We need to know, which kind of project it is? How the data is coming? We need a sample code to reproduce the issue. We do not need any confidential information,  you can create a sample which can just reproduce the issue. Then after we can get any idea about the issue. Without that we cannot provide any strong suggestion. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Teemu, Thank's for replying again, I am using Internet Explorer 11 and project is on java groovy framework.

Comment: Did you try to debug your app? If the data is coming from the database then you can check whether your app is able to access the data or not. Or Is it only a rendering issue? It can help to narrow down the issue.